# Using 3v3 zener, with actual max 3.5v, to protect Raspberry input?

Tags: raspberry-pi, zener

I'm interested in making a serial connection between an Arduino and a Raspberry.

I'm using a [SN74HC14N](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn54hc14.pdf) inverted Schmitt trigger to provide 5V logic from the 3v3 signal. (3v3 TX -> 1A; 1Y->2A; 2Y-> 5V RX)

I'm intending to use a 3v3 Zener ([BZX55C3V3](http://www.vishay.com/docs/85604/bzx55-se.pdf)) in series with 220ohm to provide 3v3 level to the Raspberry RX, but it gives me 3.5V (which is the max Vz in the datasheet).

Would this be a safe Zener to use, or should I buy a 3.0V Zener (max 3.2V) instead?

Comment: What you're proposing is beyond being a hack, and probably won't work very well. Just do what every other hobbyist does, and use the MOSFET level shifter circuit in [this app note.](http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN10441.pdf)

Comment: How about using a simple voltage divider with resistors? Also RPi pins are mostly 5V tolerant, despite this probably will decrease your service life, it works, and pins don't burn easily. So it will tolerate 3.5V, if you insist on using zener.

Comment: @ÇetinKöktürk, Thanks for the feedback :) I was thinking to use a voltage divider and zener at the same time, to protect it from voltage spikes. To have a proper design that avoids problems :) But I wasn't sure if 3.5V would be within spec. Good to know that the pins wont break from a single spike of even 5V!